# Missing System.Media.Capture.Frames namespace

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, hololens

I'm trying to develop a barcode reader app for the Microsoft HoloLens (using [this tutorial](https://mtaulty.com/2016/12/28/windows-10-uwp-qr-code-scanning-with-zxing-and-hololens/)) but I'm encountering a problem. In the code of this tutorial, there's being referenced to the `System.Media.Capture.Frames` namespace and it seems like I'm missing this namespace. Looking at the [Windows universal samples from Microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraFrames), there's also being referenced to this namespace. However, I cannot import this namespace.

- I'm running on Windows 10 Version 1607 Build 14393.693
- I have .NET Framework 4.6.2
- My Windows is fully up-to-date

Does anyone have any idea how I can get access to this namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two likely problems:

1. You need Windows.Media.Capture.Frames not System.Media.Capture.Frames
2. Windows.Media.Capture.Frames is new for build 14393 so you'll need to make sure your app targets at least that high:

Go to your app's project properties and make sure your target version is set to Build 14393 on the Application tab. Alternatively open the csproj in a text or XML editor and set the TargetPlatformVersion there:

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.14393.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
```

If your minimum version is less than 14393 then make sure you do feature detection with the [ApiInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.metadata.apiinformation.aspx) class before calling the Frames functions to make sure they exist.