# How to reference Windows.Foundation in Unity3d

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens

I want to reference `Windows.Foundation` in my Unity project. I have played with with the Scripting Runtime Version and API Compatibility level to no avail. I am using IL2CPP as the scripting backend (since .NET is being deprecated).

Can someone please help me figure out how to get Unity to recognize `Windows.Foundation`?

I saw this post which seems related but didn't fix it for me.
[Missing System.Media.Capture.Frames namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41977891/missing-system-media-capture-frames-namespace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is referenced automatically when you build to Universal Windows Platform. See this: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/IL2CPP-WindowsRuntimeSupport.html

Note, you cannot reference .winmd files in the editor as it uses Mono to power scripting, and Mono does not support referencing or calling into Windows Runtime APIs.

Comment: from that link it seems the only option is to wrap any calls to .winmd in a #define directive to prevent the Unity editor from issuing errors, is that correct?